# Can I use PyCharm windows with VirtualBox ubuntu

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, virtualbox

Can I use PyCharm (non-professional version) to develop code in windows and SSH or integrate virtualbox into PyCharm so it can send to my host in virtualbox Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Share you code folder from windows using Vagrant or your virtual box into ubuntu and edit the code from pycharm windows.  You can even debug code from ubuntu using pycharm.  I have done this for months with Vagrant VMs.